# What happened to these edits (and the associated reputation)?

Tags: support, reputation, lost-reputation

My reputation rating on SO took this hit an hour ago, and it is due to what appears to be the simultaneous deletion of multiple questions.  I am uncertain why it happened, am concerned, and would appreciate an explanation.  Going to [the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525493/how-do-i-use-the-eclipse-debugger-to-debug-a-java-application) shows that it was removed due to moderation.

Was a script run deliberately, or were we hit with a question deletion attack; what happened?

```
-12     today
-2  1 hour ago  removed     How to send a 2d Vector over UDP in c++
-2  1 hour ago  removed     How do I use the Eclipse debugger to debug a Java application?
-2  1 hour ago  removed     PHP string error; inconsistency with local and server
-2  1 hour ago  removed     Unable to start the MySQL service after a server migration
-2  1 hour ago  removed     How to use Java to print a text file on a ticket printer?
-2  1 hour ago  removed     How can all of the ZBrush Obj files be imported to make a complete model?
```

Comment: Sorry, Josh. If it makes you feel any better, this would've happened eventually anyway - just *much* more gradually. This many deletions at once should be a one-time thing.

Comment: I don't mind; it was more the quantity of questions hit rather than the loss of rep that made me concerned.

Comment: I do wonder if this will screw up some Necromancy and Archaeology badge attempts, but probably not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There was an issue with the automatic deletion of questions not actually *deleting* the questions, and it appears that the process just finally ran and a *lot* of questions just got automatically deleted by Community.

Any reputation from suggested edits on any of these automatically deleted questions (and the answers under them) has been removed.

Apparently **29,172** closed, abandoned posts were deleted.

Comment: Sad editor is sad.

Comment: Are they deleted permanently and is there any plan to restore all these? Me also lost a couple today, and thats how I noticed this post.

Comment: @MicRO those are abandoned questions, their deletion is permanent unless the OP notice and explicitly ask to undelete.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Make sense.Thanks for the info :-)