# Sudden influx of automatically deleted questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I've noticed two things this morning that appear to be related:

1. There have been more than the usual number of "why did I lose reputation" questions here on Meta Stack Overflow, all apparently related to deleted questions. Indeed, on several of the sites in the network I have seen a lot of changes to my reputation related to items being deleted. Much more than usual.
2. On the sites where I have access to the 10k tools, I see a *large* number of questions deleted by Community ♦ at around midnight EDT (-0400 UTC). From the ones I looked at they're all questions with 0 or lower score, no positively upvoted answers, and were closed back in August and September. (Some closures may be older than that, but the 10k "recently deleted" tool only goes back so far.)

So, do we have some new tweaks to the auto-delete mechanism(s)/criteria, or was a cron job not running and repaired yesterday?

Comment: Some of those questions about the rep got closed as duplciate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188502/172011

Comment: The developers are probably better able to comment on this, but we heard from Shog9 that code that was supposed to be deleting posts automatically actually wasn't. They were going to fix that, which would trigger a bunch of delayed auto-deletions at once.

Comment: Also, see animuson's answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188500/what-happened-to-these-edits-and-the-associated-reputation/188502#188502 and Shog's comment above that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The auto-deletion criteria haven't changed since [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion) was implemented, and the scheduled job *was* running. It was even logging the deletions it was doing!

...Which is where it started to get a little bit weird, since it was reporting nearly the same number of deletions - thousands - *every day*... And yet, thousands of questions were *not* getting deleted every day.

Turns out, the changes were being set up in the ORM without actually being submitted to the database. Which tends to not raise errors, but also not actually *do* anything.

So, yeah... That's happening now, which means a rather large backlog got processed last night: 29,172 questions for the new closed question cleanup task on Stack Overflow *alone*.

This should run - successfully - on a daily basis from here on out, and be much more evenly distributed as a result.

Comment: Poor database, getting delete-teased day in and day out.

Comment: I feel sorry for you son, I got 99 problems, but a database ain't one.

Comment: Thank you, Shog "ORM" Nine.

Comment: Heh... Not my fault!

Comment: Interesting.  I thought you guys were using a MicroORM - dapper if memory serves.  I didn't think they supported cool EF type stuff like lining up a bunch of operations and then calling `Save()`

Comment: There's still a bit of LINQ hanging around in older code, @Adam.

Comment: That's quite refreshing to me, that even Stack Overflow's code base has some old, un-updated crusty stuff hanging around here and there.

Comment: Thanks, @Shog9, for the explanation. I'm sure I'm not the only person who was wondering what was going on.